# IdentityServer4 with AspNetIdentity - adding role claims

Tags: authorization, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm using the IdentityServerSPA profile with IdentityServer4 and AspNetIdentity.  I want to include roles from AspNetIdentity as role claims.  I can see in my custom ProfileService that the role claims are added to the ClaimPrincipal by AspNetIdentity but they aren't making it to the client app.  I believe this is an issue with the "AllowedScopes" but I've tried adding these to the Client configuration in appsettings.json but nothing seems to work. I'm sure I'm missing something but I'm running out of time and forehead to keep banging on this particular wall.

Answer (score 0):

Not precisely.  Here is what resolved the issue for me.

In AppSettings.json add the scope for name and role

```
"IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "PrymeServer": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA",
        "Scope": "openid profile name role PrymeServerAPI"
      }
    }
  }
```

Then in the customer ProfileService, add the claims to the context

```
public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
    var roleClaims = context.Subject.FindAll(JwtClaimTypes.Role);
    var nameClaims = context.Subject.FindAll(JwtClaimTypes.Name);
    context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(roleClaims);
    context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(nameClaims);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Big shout out to Brock Allen and Dominick Baier for the assistance!